# エリンを中盤に来て削ってどうするの。

Tags: meaning, verbs

What does 来て削る mean in this sentence?

> エリンを中盤に**来て削って**どうするの。

The sentence is someone who is angry about a character being removed from the spotlight of a show, but I am especially puzzled by the usage of 来て.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 「エリンを中盤{ちゅうばん}に来{き}て削{けず}ってどうするの。」

＝

> 「中盤に来て、エリンを削ってどうするの。」

You should **not** be looking at 「来て削る」 as a phrase on its own.  Rather, it is 「中盤に来て + 削る」.

「中盤に来て」 means "**(when the show/story) is getting into full swing**".  「来る」 here means "(the show) approaching or coming near the good part" if that makes sense.

「中盤に来る」 means the same as 「中盤にさしかかる」.

> "What the heck are they thinking, putting エリン out of the show just when it's getting into full swing!"